# Adding Tuple Values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

How do I add the following values of tuples, based on the same keys in tuple? (Shown below)

```
my_tuple = [('Jack', 4), ('Sam', 3), ('Jack', 2), ('Sam',5)]
```

I want the added tuple outcome based on the common keys, **as the following below:**

```
[('Jack', 6), ('Sam', 8)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use defaultdict to collect the items with same keys and finally convert to list of tuples

Ex:

```
from collections import defaultdict


x = defaultdict(int)

my_tuple = [('Jack', 4), ('Sam', 3), ('Jack', 2), ('Sam',5)]

for key,value in my_tuple:
    x[key] += value

y = list(x.items())

print(y)
```

this prints [('Jack', 6), ('Sam', 8)]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple way of getting the answer you want.

```py
my_tuple = [('Jack', 4), ('Sam', 3), ('Jack', 2), ('Sam',5)]

new_dict = {} # new dictionary to sum values

for k,v in my_tuple:
    if k not in new_dict:
        new_dict[k] = v
    else:
        new_dict += v
```

Converting the key-value pairs in `new_dict` to a list and printing its values will return

```py
print(list(new_dict.items())) # returns [('Jack', 6), ('Sam', 8)]
```